# css: gallery view without <table>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create a page with 12 thumbnails (4X3).
I want them to speard equally and nicely in some div.

I know using `<table>` tags for styling is a bad practice.

1. How can I spread them?
2. I want thumbnails of variuse windows-style files types icons (office documents, jpg, video, audio). Any helpful framework for getting started?

TIA

Comment: I don't know what *`<tb>`* is supposed to mean, but it's just fine to use tables for tabular data - this is what are they for.

Comment: @duri I wouldn't use a table for this. What if I want to change to grid to 3x4 at some point? Just use div around the images set to `float: left`. Just remember to add `overflow: hidden;` to the container.

Comment: The sentiment that drove OP to avoid tables reflects the following philosophy (which I'm not endorsing, but just stating that it is out there):  tables are for conveying structure intrinsic in the data (which the browser does by laying the data out a certain way), not for layout of essentially unstructured data.  Since the four images in one row are not related to each other any more than any other images, the use of table in this case would be purely for layout. Personally, if my objective were to get this job done, I'd use a table. If it were a learning exercise, I would not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/45TwK/1/

but it all depends on your convenience

Answer (score 1):

If your data is tabular, a.k.a fit in a table, then by all means use a `<table>` (that's why they put it in the specs), but if you're making something like a gallery, whose only point is to display images, keep reading.

No need for framework. Simply float them all and clear on every 4th image.

**[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/45TwK/)**

It uses the CSS `nth-child` pseudo selector, which is not supported in IE8-, but then again, neither does `display: table-*` so you're good. The code used in this example (CSS only):

```
#grid img {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 2px;
}
#grid img:nth-child(4n+1) { /* Counting starts from 0 */
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Truth's answer: if you also want IE8 support, I'd do it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/HcP7q/

If you also want IE6+7 support, I'd go for a table - there's nothing wrong with using a table if you need a tabular layout.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with using a table if you need a tabular layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `div`'s. This makes sure you are flexible in your layout.

HTML

```
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="first"><img src="someimage.png" alt="alt-text"></div>
  <div><img src="someimage.png" alt="alt-text"></div>
  <div><img src="someimage.png" alt="alt-text"></div>
  <div class="last"><img src="someimage.png" alt="alt-text"></div>
  <div class="first"><img src="someimage.png" alt="alt-text"></div>
  <div><img src="someimage.png" alt="alt-text"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.gallery { overflow: hidden; width: 230px; padding: 10px; }
.gallery > div { width: 40px; margin-right: 10px; float: left; }
.gallery > div.last { margin-right: 0; }
```

This technique uses some more HTML (`.first` and `.last` classes but you have to blame IE for this and not me)

Comment: be aware however that the child selector (>) doesn't work in ie6 and can be buggy in ie7