# How to style a photo gallery?

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a method to design a photo gallary, I am currently using table but not sure if its a correct method to do it or not, also not sure about styling.

It has many images, upload is used to upload photos and message is used to show upload messages.

I just need to show the images and allow users to save images on the server, and show the messages, (uploaded / can not upload). I can show the images, save them and send the messages to the message section but not sure *how to style it*.

*Another problem* is that I need all images to be in the same size, as each is in different size now.

I need it to be the same on all browsers.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><img 1></td>
    <td>upload photo btn</td>
    <td><label>message</label></td>
    <td><img 3></td>
    <td>upload photo btn</td>
    <td><label>message</label></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you want the gallery to do? enlarge onClick etc, or do you simply want the images displayed nicely on a page?

Comment: just need to show them. question is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semantically tables should be used for tabular data.

Check out the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546792/css-gallery-view-without-table) for some options.
Depending on the age of the browsers you want to support, you could also consider using a [flex box layout](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/19/css3-flexible-box-layout-explained/). Flex box is nice and easy to code but not fully supported in all browsers yet.

Answer (score 0):

According to me this shouldn't be accomplished using tables, the better way to do is by using CSS3 `column-count` property, this way you can cut-split your content to whatever number of columns you want to, this way you don't have to use tables too..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/M6tSt/)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/M6tSt/1/) (Added `-webkit` support)

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
    column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
}

.holder {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

> Note: `column-count` CSS3 property is not widely supported, but there
>   are many polyfills available out, you can search online and use it for
>   cross browser compatibility

Comment: @JackRamzi it is responsive, resize the windows and you'll see the images resize